# How to get routes in the database that intersects circle?

Tags: postgis, sql, query, linestring, circle

I have routes (linestrings) recorded in the database. I want to create a query which returns the routes that have some commonality with a circle whose center and radius are passed as parameter.

I tried this way:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   routes
WHERE  ST_Touches(geom, (ST_Buffer(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-12.988542214345332 -38.44563066959381)'), 100, 8)))
```

Is it correct?

Answer (score 6):

No, probably not. I'm going to assume from the coordinates of your point that you are working in longitude/latitude coordinates, but that you want to express your distances in meters. Rather than building a real "circle", recognize that for the purpose of a true/false test you can express the query as a distance calculation.

```
SELECT routes.*
FROM routes
WHERE ST_DWithin(
                 routes.geom::geography,
                 'POINT(-12.988542214345332 -38.44563066959381)'::geography,
                 100
                );
```

Also note that if you don't think you're working well below the equator (-38.4S) you should reverse your coordinates, as the coordinate order in PostGIS is X/Y or lon/lat not Y/X.